# rxBindings - How to know what consumer type should be when debouncing click events?

Tags: rx-android, rx-java2, rx-binding

using [rxBindings](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) im trying to slow down a click event but i would like to know what the parameter is need.

For example, here is a call i am doing on a imageview. So ImageView v;

```
RxView.clicks(v)
                  .throttleFirst(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {

                      @Override
                      public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Object v) throws Exception {
                          showBottomSheet(getAdapterPosition());
                      }
                  });

              but im im not sure what the parameter in accept should be ?  

              I was expecting i would get the view here but when i try changing the type to View i get an error of no such method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/ViewClickObservable.java) of the `Observable` generate using `RxView.clicks()`, you will see that when the click happens, the following code is triggered:

```
observer.onNext(Notification.INSTANCE);
```

that is defined in the library, as:

```
public enum Notification {
  INSTANCE
}
```

It is just a convenient way for indicating that the event happened, it doesn't carry any extra information.

Comment: so then  i can just always ignore the parameter, it has no use to me right ?  because what use would it be for me to use Notification ?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore it. If you look at the old version of the library, that is based on RxJava 1, you will see that it uses `subscriber.onNext(null);` when the click is triggered. But, RxJava 2 doesn't allow null value anymore, so when you just want to send something that doesn't carry any extra data, then you have to pass something.